# How do I get a handle on a textbox on a Microsoft Access form from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm writing a C# application which pulls a string of text from a MySql database, opens a form contained within a Microsoft Access database and populates a textbox on the form with this string.

The first two parts I'm fine with, I can pull the string from the MySql database and open the Access database, but I am struggling to get a handle on the textbox.

How do I, after pressing a button on a C# Windows Form application, populate a textbox on a Microsoft Access Form with a string contained within the C# application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first of all check with Spy++ to verify that the textBox you see in the Access form is a normal and reachable one... you never know with access ;-)

after that, you can follow one of the trillions questions here in SO about how to get/reach external applications's textboxes, for example here:

[Insert text into the textbox of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539187/insert-text-into-the-textbox-of-another-application)

[FindWindowEx - Select textbox if there are several textboxes with same classname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176710/findwindowex-select-textbox-if-there-are-several-textboxes-with-same-classname)